# Replace values that are "roughly" the same

Tags: r, replace, keyword

I have a database containing films watched by people and for each film keywords are associated with it.

So I tried to see for each keyword how many occurrences there were and I saw that some were not counted together because for example the capital letter is missing.

ie: "england" and "England" are not counted together.

I would like to be able to find an algo that replaces its keywords are approximately the same.
For example, ask this algo to replace all the words that have 95% of the letters in common with the first value found in the column.

I don't know if this is possible or if I am clear enough.

Thank you

Comment: Try using tolower()

Comment: Maybe also relevant package: `stringdist::stringdist()`